# how to overload > operator for a queue

Tags: c++

i have a priority queue and i have defined like this:

```
priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>,greater<Node*>> myQueue;
```

i have to add to queue on the basis of a parameter param and i have overloaded it like this

```
bool Node::operator>(const Node& right) const
{   
    return param>right.param;
}
```

since the overload function doesnt take a pointer object, how should i change it so that my overloaded function is called.
i am adding to queue this way:

```
Node *myNode
myQueue.add(myNode);
```

i cant pass the myNode without making as pointer object.
please guide ..

@Sellibitze
i have done something like this

```
    template<typename Node, typename Cmp = std::greater<Node> >
struct deref_compare : std::binary_function<Node*,Node*,bool>
{
    deref_compare(Cmp const& cmp = Cmp())
    : cmp(cmp) {}

    bool operator()(Node* a, Node* b) const {
        return cmp(*a,*b);
    }

private:
    Cmp cmp;
};

typedef deref_compare<Node,std::greater<Node> > my_comparator_t;
priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>,my_comparator_t> open;
```

i am filled with errors.

Comment: The default template parameter "Cmp" should really be std::less even though you override the default by explicitly naming std::greater later. Also, it doesn't hurt using pointers to const (see my answer below). Sorry, but "I am filled with errors" is not a good error description. I didn't test deref_compare but it looks good to me.

Comment: Read the errors.
Fix them.
sellibitze's answer gives you a _very_ good direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write your own functor for the comparison because you can't overload operator> for pointers. So, instead of greater you would be using your own dedicated class with the appropriate function call operator. This could be even done generically.

```
template<typename T, typename Cmp = std::less<T> >
struct deref_compare : std::binary_function<T const*,T const*,bool>
{
    deref_compare(Cmp const& cmp = Cmp())
    : cmp(cmp) {}

    bool operator()(T const* a, T const* b) const {
        return cmp(*a,*b);
    }
private:
    Cmp cmp;
};

typedef deref_compare<Node,std::greater<Node> > my_comparator_t;
```

Edit1: I just realized you could do it even *more* generically, with iterators instead of pointers. ;-)

Edit2: If you're not comfortable with the template and don't need this generalization you could just as well use

```
struct my_node_ptr_compare
{
    bool operator()(Node const* a, Node const* b) const {
        return *a > *b;
    }
};

priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>,my_node_ptr_compare> foo;
```

Comment: ok thanks for the code, so i need to declare the queue now as 
priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>,deref_compare> myQueue; 
is this correct?

Comment: No, not deref_compare. deref_compare is a class template but you need a type. See the typedef. You can use my_comparator_t.

Comment: i have pasted the code which i have done, and its giving me errors...
please let me know where i am wrong

Comment: Error 1 error C2365: 'deref_compare<Node,Cmp>::cmp' : redefinition; previous definition was 'member function' 
getting this error after i defined cmp(Node*a Node *b) fucntion is Cmp class

Comment: In the code I posted I did NOT declare cmp to be a member function. It looks like you introduced errors while "copying" it to your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the operator>() as a friend-of-Nodes function taking two Nodes.

Use the `friend` keyword.

Some refs:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/465sdshe(VS.80).aspx

Edit: This won't work in the pointer case, but will work in the regular Nodes case.

Comment: If you look closely you'll see that harshit wants to order pointers differently, *pointers*.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to implement a compare function that takes Node pointers as its parameters, like this:

```
bool nodePtrGreater(Node const *a, Node const *b) {
  return *a > *b;
}
```

This function should use the operator> of your Node class properly.

[edit] The old version didn't define the queue correctly.

Create your priority queue like this:

```
priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>, bool(*)(Node const *, Node const *)> myQueue(nodePtrGreater);
```

Comment: You could, of course, implement this as a function object, but I don't think it is necessary in this particular case. If you want genericity, you could implement this as a function template.

Comment: This function should use the operator> of your Node class properly. I didnt get this. do i need to overload > operator. If yes how..

Comment: Like you did in your original code (the bool Node::operator> thing there)

Comment: Hold on ... nodePtrGreater is a function that can decay to a function pointer but you used it as type parameter. That won't work, of course.

Comment: Ah, you are right. This one should work, although it is getting uglier :(